# Generic type not resolving by DI in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple Generic Repository that takes a type T, T is constrained to be a class. Pretty straight forward stuff but .NET Core isn't able to satisfy the dependency. Not sure, what am I doing wrong.

Error:

```
System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'Building.Manager.Domain.Society', on 'Building.Manager.Repository.GenericRepository`1[T]'
 violates the constraint of type 'T'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'Building.Manager.Domain.Society', on 'Building
.Manager.Repository.GenericRepository`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.


 public class Society : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Flat> Flats { get; set; }

        public Society() => this.Flats = new List<Flat>();
    }
```

BaseEntity is a simple abstract class with a protected constructor.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {}




public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class, IGenericRepository<T>
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        protected GenericRepository() { }
        public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }}
```

Configure method on StartUp.cs as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped<ISocietyService, SocietyService>();

            services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Building Manager API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is T a class type AND an IGenericRepository<T>?  Did you possibly mean to put:  public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class  instead of where T : class, IGenericRepository<T>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably wanted to make `GenericRepository` implement the interface, but instead you made a constraint on `T`. You want

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

Not

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : where T : class, IGenericRepository<T>
```